# How do I mount the data from two different versions of the same docker container/volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am composing a web application using separate docker containers for nodejs, nginx and some static web data.

I want to access two different versions of the web data. My first thought was to create a data only container, and then mount the data directory in two different places in the nginx container

The Dockerfile for the static data looks something like:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN mkdir -p /data
ADD build/* /data/
```

I was hoping to compose it, doing something like:

```
nginx-site:
    image: my-nginx-image:version
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
    - data-version-1
    - data-version-2
    links:
    - node-app

node-app:
    image: my-node-app-image:version
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"

data-version-1:
    image: my-data-image:version1
    volume:
    - /data1:/data

data-version-2:
    image: my-data-image:version2
    volume:
    - /data2:/data
```

But I think I completely misunderstood the volume mounting. The /data1, /data2 volumes are coming from the host instead of mounting two different directories from the data container into the nginx container.

(Even if it's not the best pattern, this all works fine if I don't want to have two versions of the data)

I have also read up on docker data volumes, but I wonder whether I would run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question using data containers is not the best way to go. I would use [version 2 volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#/volumes-volumedriver) for docker-compose. All of your services get nested under a `services` key and we add a new top level `volumes` key where we create our volumes. Then we mount the volumes as normal using a volumes key under the service we want to have access to the volume. See the revised compose file:

`version: "2"
services:
  nginx-site:
      image: my-nginx-image:version
      ports:
      - "80:80"
      volumes:
      - data1:/var/www/html/data1
      - data2:/var/www/html/data2
      links:
      - node-app
  node-app:
      image: my-node-app-image:version
      ports:
      - "5000:5000"
volumes:
  data1:
    driver: local
  data2:
    driver: local`

- **Note the version key to enable these features**
- I've made the assumption you would like two different accessible directories within the nginx container under `/var/www/html` adjust this as needed
- This method **wont expose folders to the host** if you need this see the next revision below
- By using version 2 volumes we no longer have dead data containers and our data is abstracted away within `/var/lib/docker` on the host.

`version: "2"
services:
  nginx-site:
      image: my-nginx-image:version
      ports:
      - "80:80"
      volumes:
      - ./data1:/var/www/html/data1
      - ./data2:/var/www/html/data2
      links:
      - node-app
  node-app:
      image: my-node-app-image:version
      ports:
      - "5000:5000"`

- This creates two directories `data1` and `data2` in the directory where your `docker-compose.yml` file so you can add things as required and they will appear in the container. **Note the addition of ./ to signify current directory**

I hope this has helped clarify things

Dylan

### Edit

You can mount the same volume data in two different directories by specifiying the same volume but a different mount path. For example `data1:/var/www/html/data1` and `data1:/var/www/html/data2` would mount the same volume data in both folders

Comment: Thanks for that @dylan-scott. I had come to more or less the same conclusion. What I was really trying to do was seed a container or volume with the data I wanted to store at those mount points, but after doing some more reading/investigation, it seems that this is not really a thing in docker, and the data needs to be copied across separately during deployment. Any thoughts on this would also be appreciated :)

Comment: @nat-k No problem glad I could help - I agree populating docker volumes can be somewhat problematic - I would suggest doing this as part of your `docker-entrypoint.sh` foryour image - ie do some conditional checks in bash to see if your files exist and then copy them from a mounted volume like the second revision I did (host mounting). Alternatively you could use the COPY command in the Dockerfile to seed the image with your data. This does have its drawbacks that any changes to that data requires a image rebuild however. It's probably a case of experiment and see tbh :)